# Symfony - How do you find a post that has an id and slug in the route?

Tags: php, symfony, crud, routes

How do you query for a specific post that has an id and also has a slug in the route? This is for updating a specific post. I've tried adding in the slug into update route to no avail (the not found exception triggers), what is the proper way of finding a post with a id and a slug value?

Routes:

Show

```
 BloggerBlogBundle_blog_show:
    path:  /{id}/{slug}
    defaults: { _controller: BloggerBlogBundle:Blog:show }
    requirements:
        methods:  GET
        id: \d+
```

Update

```
BloggerBlogBundle_blog_update:
path:  /{id}/{slug}/update
defaults: { _controller: BloggerBlogBundle:Blog:update, id: $id }
requirements:
    id: \d+
```

Controller:

BlogController(update action)

```
  public function updateAction($id, Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getManager();

    $blog = $em->getRepository('BloggerBlogBundle:Blog')
        ->find($id);

    if (!$blog) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException(
            'No blog was found for this id' . $id
        );
    }

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($blog)
        ->add('title', 'text')
        ->add('author', 'text')
        ->add('blog', 'text')
        ->add('image', 'text')
        ->add('tags', 'text')
        ->add('save', 'submit')
        ->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em->flush();

        // return new Response('Blog was updated successfully');
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('BloggerBlogBundle_homepage'));
    }

    $build['form'] = $form->createView();

    return $this->render('BloggerBlogBundle:Blog:create.html.twig', $build);
}
```

Comment: sorry i'm a bit confused with your question, are you trying to get your show action to work or is something wrong with your update action?

Comment: having slugs in update routes is generally not the best idea - it requires additional work. If you update the slug ... your current url becomes invalid. I strongly recommend you to stick with just the id in the url-pattern for admin-routes!

Comment: @Derick F I am trying to find/load the specific post for updating, however it's not finding the post for the update action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, figured out what I was doing wrong. Needed to pass in $slug into the updateAction parameter and use findOneBy(array) per nifr (thanks for the assist).

Updated route:

```
BloggerBlogBundle_blog_update:
path:  /{id}/{slug}/update
defaults: { _controller: BloggerBlogBundle:Blog:update }
requirements:
    id: \d+
```

Updated controller:

```
public function updateAction($id, $slug, Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getManager();

    $blog = $em->getRepository('BloggerBlogBundle:Blog')
        ->findOneBy(array(
            'id'   => $id,
            'slug' => $slug
        ));

    if (!$blog) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException(
            'No blog was found for this id/slug: ' . $id. $slug
        );
    }

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($blog)
        ->add('title', 'text')
        ->add('author', 'text')
        ->add('blog', 'text')
        ->add('image', 'text')
        ->add('tags', 'text')
        ->add('save', 'submit')
        ->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em->flush();

        // return new Response('Blog was updated successfully');
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('BloggerBlogBundle_homepage'));
    }

    $build['form'] = $form->createView();

    return $this->render('BloggerBlogBundle:Blog:create.html.twig', $build);
}
```

Comment: I'd also recommend checking @ParamConverter annotation. Very useful for id => entity conversions like this: http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html

Answer (score 0):

You can query for an entry matching `id` and `slug` at the same time using doctrine's `findOneBy(array $criteria)` method.

```
$request    = $this->getRequest()->request;
$em         = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$repository = $em->getRepository('AcmeYourBundle:Entity'):

$entity = $repository->findOneBy(array(
    'id'   => $request->get('id'),
    'slug' => $request->get('slug'),
));
```

The documentation chapter [Working with objects # By simple conditions](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/working-with-objects.html#by-simple-conditions) covers this topic.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it still didn't find the post will have to dig into it further.

Comment: out of curiosity, i noticed you're route it path:  /{id}/{slug}  does your url have a / at the end of it?  if so then your slug will also have a / at the end of it making your slug not equal your entity.  change your path to path:  /{id}/{slug}/ so that the extra '/' will get taken out of the slug

Comment: i changed it to "path:  /{id}/{slug}/update" and the ('No blog was found for this id/slug: ' . $id. $slug) finds the correct id and slug per the error message yet the update isn't working. Thanks for the suggestion though.